# MagicalRecord MR_saveOnlySelfAndWait doesn't work within saveWithBlock

Tags: ios, objective-c, magicalrecord

I'm getting the grips with MagicalRecord 2.3 and it seems as though if I run MR_saveOnlySelfAndWait within a saveWithBlock, nothing persists (the callback has a success flag of NO and error is nil).

However, when I run MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait within that block it works no problem. The object in question only has one attribute (a String) and it's set.

Is this due to the fact that saveWithBlock runs on a background thread anyway? Pretty confused here.

Answer (score 0):

MagicalRecord is designed to work with nested contexts. Te rule with regard to nested contexts is that if a context does not have a parent, then calling save will persist changes to the store. If there is a parent, then a save will only persist changes to the parent, and not to the store. This is the reasoning behind the two methods. Choose the proper save for your situations